# Upgrade from MySQL 4 to Mysql 5 - same my.cnf - lots of random disconnects

Tags: mysql, networking, mysql5

I've recently moved from MySQL4 to MySQL5 (we had apps that required MySQL4 which we'd finally replaced)

Since then, I've been having LOTS of issues similar to:-

```
connect() failed: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
```

Yes, that is System Error 0 - "Success".

I've no idea why this is happening - but want to find out why

Here's my (sanitised) my.cnf

```
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
language    = /usr/share/mysql/english
skip-external-locking

key_buffer      = 1048M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack = 2M
thread_cache_size   = 16384
sort_buffer_size    = 256K
read_buffer_size    = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size    = 256K
tmp_table_size      = 512M
max_heap_table_size = 512M
query_cache_size    = 512M
thread_concurrency  = 16
set-variable = table_cache=16384
max_connections     = 500

wait_timeout = 3600

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1024M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 8M
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_thread_concurrency = 8
innodb_file_per_table=1

query_cache_limit       = 1024M
query_cache_size        = 512M
query_cache_type = 1
server-id       = 9
log_bin         = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M

expire_logs_days    = 3

skip-bdb

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]
prompt                  = (\u@atlas) [\d]>\\_

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

**EDIT** I changed the my.cnf above - I've just realised it was the one from the old server! Also - this is 5.0, not 5.1

Comment: Do you have mysql library updated on all clients as well?

Comment: Varying clients... all at least 5.0 though

Answer (score 0):

For one, get rid of the line "skip-bdb" as posted here: [Mysql-Server-5.1 upgrade problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/265372/mysql-server-5-1-upgrade-problem/265399#comment-244605)

Comment: Crap - my.cnf from wrong server!

Comment: Contains the same line reading "skip-bdb"... Drop it / comment it. And check out what @uesp said too.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a detailed [bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28359) that explains this error with a possible solution to increase the `connect_timeout` parameter.

Comment: Hmmm... I've changed that - will know tomorrow (from the error reports) whether it's working :)

Comment: Nope - it didn't